# Using jQuery LazyLoad for image grid with AngularJS SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lazy-loading

I've been playing with a GUI for [boom](http://github.com/holman/boom), and today I thought I'd add Lazy Loading of images. The GUI is built with AngularJS. Here's the Gist with the working version that loads all the images: https://gist.github.com/brock/6724161

And here's my latest version that adds lazyloading: https://gist.github.com/brock/6746909 
Right now it just shows the placeholders for the images, but they never load.

What's interesting is that if I open the Chrome Console, I can just type `$('img.lazy').lazyload()` and it operates as I'd expect, but I haven't determined yet why this doesn't ever fire on the page load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because on the time `$('img.lazy').lazyload()` is executed (window.onload event), AngularJS didn't link view to your model, and hasn't even fetched it yet (get .boom -> $scope.lists).

To make it AngularJS way, you should use a directive for any DOM manipulation (that is, using jQuery plugin that manipulates DOM).

I added directive, see this: http://plnkr.co/edit/eOXp9eQKIukCDNR90xje

I execute lazyload() function inside $timeout, because attributes on img DOM element must be interpolated first ({{ url }} filled) for lazyload() to work properly.